# How to Override `Config.xml`

Tags: magento-1.9, configuration

How to Override `Config.xml`  I added New Order status in this location

```
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/config.xml
```

it's not good to edit core file

```
<invoice translate="label">
                        <label>invoice</label>
                        <statuses>
                            <pending default="1"/>
                        </statuses>
                        <visible_on_front>1</visible_on_front>
                    </invoice>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible to override `config.xml`. You can use same xml tag structure to define custom status as already defined in `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/config.xml`.

You need to create your custom module **OR** you can also add it from admin.

> Step 1: Create file app\etc\modules\Rohit_Status.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
         <Rohit_Status>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends/>
        </Rohit_Status>
    </modules>
</config>
```

> Step 2: Create file app\code\local\Rohit\Status\etc\config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Rohit_Status>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Rohit_Status>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <sales>
            <order>
                <states>
                    <invoice translate="label">
                        <label>invoice</label>
                        <statuses>
                            <pending default="1"/>
                        </statuses>
                        <visible_on_front>1</visible_on_front>
                    </invoice>
                </states>
            </order>
        </sales>
    </global>
</config>
```

**OR**

You can also add statuses from admin by navigating to `Admin > System > Order Statuses`

Clear the cache and you are set to go

Hope it helps you

Comment: You mean create New Module right

Comment: Yes create new module and define this above code in your module's `config.xml`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add/remove/edit particular section from Magento admin then it will be little bit different because we can’t remove section by just copying system.xml in local codepool.
For e.g I want to remove `“gift options”` from Sales configuration page in admin panel.
We need to create custom module which will be depend on “Mage_GiftMessage” Module

> Step 1: Create file app\etc\modules\Arunendra_Mymodule.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
         <Arunendra_Mymodule>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_GiftMessage />
            </depends>
        </Arunendra_Mymodule>
    </modules>
</config>
```

> Step 2: Create file app\code\local\Arunendra\Mymodule\etc\config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Arunendra_Mymodule>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Arunendra_Mymodule>
    </modules>
</config>
```

> Step 3: Create file app\code\local\Arunendra\Mymodule\etc\system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <sections>
        <sales>
            <groups>
                <gift_options translate="label" module="giftmessage">
                    <label>Gift Options </label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>0</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>0</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                 </gift_options>
            </groups>
        </sales>
    </sections>
</config>
```

In same way you can override any system.xml configuration file.
Let me know if you have any query?

Comment: I am not getting what you are explaining.

Comment: Please ready my description first.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create a new custom module where you can define a new config.xml which will override the one from core

Answer (score 0):

For XML Follow as @Rohit

AND for to just add/modify order status

> You can add order status FROM admin->System->Order Statuses as well